# Disconnecting from ChromeCast doesn't stop the video playback

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast, castcompanionlibrary

My users are complaining that when they click the disconnect after playing a video, it does not stop the video.

Is that something the CastCompanionLibrary should be doing or do I need to trap the disconnect and do it myself?

I thought maybe by the time I get the disconnect event it is probably too late for me to be telling the app to stop the video playback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CCL can do that if needed, but it is advised that you implement this in the receiver logic. I have explained the proper way of doing that in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22108092/2765813). Back to the first statement I made, you can use the following API to instruct the CCL to stop the running app on disconnect:

`mVideoCastManager.setStopOnDisconnect(true)`

You need to call that somewhere early from your application, say when you create the VideoCastManager singleton. But as I said earlier and is explained in the referenced post, that is not the proper way of doing that.

Comment: That's funny I just realized I was specifically calling that with `false` in my code. Thanks.