# Enqueue multiple media items

Tags: ios, chromecast, google-cast

Can I enqueue multiple tracks to be played on a chromecast receiver app one by one? 
I just want to play a simple playlist. So i enqueue 5 tracks, my iOS client goes into background mode when playing the second track, and I want my chromecast receiver app to play the remaining 3 tracks. Is this possible?

Actually it's comments to the `loadMedia:autoplay:` that make me think that this should be possible:

```
/**
 * Loads, **enqueues (at the end of the queue)**, and optionally starts playback of a new media
 * item.
 *
 * @param mediaInfo An object describing the media item to load.
 * @param autoplay Whether playback should start immediately.
 * @return The request ID, or kGCKInvalidRequestID if the message could not be sent.
 */
- (NSInteger)loadMedia:(GCKMediaInformation *)mediaInfo autoplay:(BOOL)autoplay;
```

I tried to call this method for two `mediaInfo` objects, setting autoplay only for the first one, but it still plays only one track.

But other than in comments `loadMedia:autoplay:` I did not find any indication of this `queue`, how I can get it, how I can dequeue items, etc. So is this just a wrong comment or does this queue exist somewhere?

P.S. It's not background playback support I am looking for, thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22011821/chromecast-background-video-playback-support-ios) I know it can not be done, I just want to enqueue multiple items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comment on that method is wrong and we already have an internal bug on that; it will be fixed in the next release. Back to your question, the current Styled or Default receiver do not have queuing capabilities; you need to roll out your own custom receiver; we have a [GitHub sample project](https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideosPlaylist-chrome) that shows how it can be done. We have plans to add such functionality in the future releases but no date is yet announced for that.

Update: Our two receivers now support queueing, along with the Cast SDK. See our documentation for more information.